# Is there a way to join tables using "As" Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, matching, spaces

I am trying to create a query which joins 2 tables together based on First Name and last Name. I successfully got my substrings to split the names from one column into 2 named FirstName and LastName. This is supposed to let me match these columns up so they can get the proper extension, phone number, department, and Name. However I am doing something wrong here. My method of doing this is not working or it will throw an error.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Users.Names, CHARINDEX(' ', Users.Names + ' ') + 1, 8000)AS LastName, SUBSTRING(Users.Names, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Users.Names) - 1) AS FirstName,Users.Extension, GA.[First], GA.[Last], GA.Department, GA.Phone, GA.Mobile
FROM GlobalAddress AS GA 
    Left Join Users ON GA.[First] = substring(Users.Names,1,charindex(' ',Users.Names) ) AND SUBSTRING(Users.Names, CHARINDEX(' ', Users.Names + ' ') + 1, 8000) = Ga.[Last]
WHERE GA.[Last] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Users.Extension
```

My thinking was that I could swap out the Left Join with:

```
Users ON GA.[First] = FirstName AND Ga.[Last] = LastName
```

But that throws an error. Invalid column name 'FirstName'.

[An example of the format i'm following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H74A.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: [The problem is that the first few people are not properly getting the extension and for some reason their names are not being split up. The issue isn't with the data on the table though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJjj.png)

Edit2: [An Example Of Global Addresses Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Hnf.png)

[An Example of Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwwtF.png)

Comment: no need for 'as' just alias table like this:  'GlobalAddress GA'

Comment: if you give us a sample of GlobalAddress and Users tables with the same structure, and some data it will help us to even give you a better approach. As you might miss something in between that was not mentioned in your post!.

Comment: @iSR5 I have added snips of the data I am pulling from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to create aliases for columns, because their lengthy body appears in many places. CROSS APPLY can do this:

```
SELECT
    q.LastName,
    q.FirstName,
    Users.Extension, GA.[First], GA.[Last], GA.Department, GA.Phone, GA.Mobile
FROM 
Users
cross apply (select
    SUBSTRING(Users.Names, CHARINDEX(' ', Users.Names + ' ') + 1, 8000)AS LastName,
    left(Users.Names, CHARINDEX(' ', Users.Names + ' ') - 1) AS FirstName
    )q
Right Join GlobalAddress AS GA 
    ON GA.[First] = q.FirstName 
    AND q.LastName = Ga.[Last]
WHERE GA.[Last] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Users.Extension
```

When a CROSS APPLY has no FROM in it, it can be perceived as creating an alias for its columns.

Comment: I am given this error. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Users.Names" could not be bound.
What could I do to fix that?

Comment: Try it again, I put the Users table first so cross apply can draw its data

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . I was going to edit to your original answer, to add a mention of  `values()` instead of `select`.  However, I saw that your query was not was not syntactically correct because of the reference to `users`, so I figured I needed to provide another answer.

Comment: Nicely done, I am a bit susceptible to those syntax errors.

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. That is the error I was given. I was getting that before when I just used its original name. I believe it doesn't like the -1 in ....Users.Names) - 1) AS FirstName

Comment: Try it now, I have stolen Gordon's Firstname :)

Comment: The multi-part identifier "u.Names" could not be bound. That is the current error. I wish I could help  you with this but I have never messed with the method you are using here.

Comment: OK, try it again now

Comment: Awesome that works now. However it seems that my theory was incorrect. This does not solve my issue of the data being null for lastName and FirstName for some users. I'll mess around with it myself and see what I can do. Thanks for the help. It would appear the real error is within my SUBSTRINGS

Comment: I selected you as the best Answer. I added some OR to the from allowing for different conditions to be met. It now properly finds all of the users with extensions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use original value on join - not alias

```
...Users ON GA.[First] = SUBSTRING(Users.Names, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Users.Names) - 1)  ...
```

Comment: Same for last name too

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. I am now given this error

Comment: what exactly is the error in your original query?  what are you expected results? what is the sample data you are working with?

Comment: I made an edit to show an image of my data and the problem

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  This could be the first time when I think a `right join` is the simpler way to do something:

```
SELECT v.LastName, v.FirstName, u.Extension, GA.[First], GA.[Last],
       GA.Department, GA.Phone, GA.Mobile
from Users u cross apply
     (values (substring(u.Names, CHARINDEX(' ', u.Names + ' ') + 1, 8000),
              left(u.Names, CHARINDEX(' ', u.Names + ' ') - 1)
             )
     ) v(LastName, Firstname) right join
     GlobalAddress GA
     on GA.[First] = v.firstname and
        Ga.[Last] = v.lastname
where GA.[Last] is not null
order by u.Extension;
```

I do wonder if you really want an outer join.  Note that you *can* do this with a `left join` and parentheses.

Comment: My answer looks like Linoff's, I am happy :)

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'. Thanks so much for the help. Currently this gives me an error. I think the from doesnt like my ....u.Names + ' ') - 1). I was having this error before and I think its the -1.

Comment: hm, I think Gordon forgot to enclose the left() in  ( )

Comment: Either I do not understand what you mean by that @GeorgeMenoutis or enclosing the left doesnt work for me

Comment: Scratch that, replace 8000), with 8000)),(

Comment: Dang. That didn't work I feel like once we get this error sorted we may just have it. Fingers crossed. Thanks for all of the help and quick responses.

Comment: Ok, let me describe it better: make sure the syntax is: cross apply (values (function1),(function2)) v(Lastname,Firstname)

Comment: Yea I get it now. It doesn't seem to be fixing the error